# oracle sql to find the rows with one or more duplicate results in a same table

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have the below sample data set and I'm trying to come up with a query to find one or more duplicate rows from the same table

TABLE A:  with 2 columns as below

```
CODE_NAME, RESULT 
ABC        1
BBC        1
ZZZ        5
ZZZ        6
ZZZ        7
KBC        2
ZBC        2
CCC        2
XYZ        3
MNC        4
```

And my output should give all the unique rows with duplicate values in the result column such as below

```
CODE_NAME, RESULT 
    ABC        1
    BBC        1       
    KBC        2
    ZBC        2
    CCC        2
```

i tried below but its not giving me correct result
select A t1, A t2
where A.result = b.result
and a.code_name <> b.code_name

Appreciate other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.result = t.result and t2.code_name <> t.code_name
             );
```

For performance on a large dataset, you want an index on `(result, code_name)`.

You might find it more convenient to have one row per duplicated result:

```
select result,
       listagg(code_name, ',') within group (order by code_name)
from t
group by result
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response for the data set I have... exists is taking a while to run whereas the listagg is much faster. thanks for that suggestion.